# Showing Standard Out in Lazarus IDE when running program?

Tags: lazarus

I am just trying out Lazarus IDE out of curiosity, with the simplest Pascal program possible:

```
program project1;

begin
  WriteLn('Hi there');
end.
```

When I run it with F9 in the IDE, I thought I would see the standard output in some window, but I cannot find it.

Does Lazarus provide a standard out view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does and console apps work fine in Lazarus.  Probably all you need to do is to add a Readln() statement at the very end of your program so that the console window stays open long enough to be visible, otherwise the console window will close automatically as soon as the program completes execution.

```
program project1;

begin
  WriteLn('Hi there');
  ReadLn();
end.
```

However, it seems that Lazarus behaves somewhat differently:  in Windows, the terminal window (aka console) displays automatically when the app starts execution, but may require a final `ReadLn` as above for it to stay on-screen long enough to be visible.  On Ubuntu v.1704, to display the console window, I need to go to View | Debug windows | Terminal Output to get it to display (this is what Ctrl-Alt-O does, of course); once I've done that, the console window stays on-screen even after I close and re-open Lazarus.  I imagine that somewhere in Lazarus there is a setting that makes the console window visible by default in new projects.

<s>ISTR that somewhere in Lazarus there is an option to not display the console window, but I can't find at at the moment, so try what I have suggested and see if that works for you.</s>

Of course, if you put a debugger breakpoint somewhere before the end of your program code, you should find that the console window is on-screen when the breakpoint trips.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I couldn't see any window; even when setting a breakpoint on the ReadLn() line and stopping there in debugging. I did, however, find this: https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=31201.0 and with Ctrl+Alt+O I can bring up the console window.

Comment: I did also install some plugin to make the IDE a single window (can't remember its name). Is it possible that this is the cause?

Comment: Very possibly that might be the cause.  In suggest you do a fresh FPC + Lazatus install to a different directory.  If that still doesn't work, have a look at this thread: https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=42500.0

Comment: I think so. I failed to mention, but I am running on Ubuntu. I didn't know that the Windows build behaves differently. I assumed they would work exactly the same.